# how to generate link to "Manage Page" in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I'm developing simple pages navigation portlet, and for each page I would like to have link to its "Manage Page" ("Manage > Page" in the top navigation bar)

Do you have any ideas how this link can be generated?

Thanks,
Karol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I needed to add another answer as the comment had less charachters. For each url you have to create pageSettingsURL as under. Write the following logic in a loop for all the layouts of the community you are interested in using LayoutLocalServiceUtil class and pass the plid

PortletURL pageSettingsURL = new PortletURLImpl(
                    request, PortletKeys.LAYOUT_MANAGEMENT, plid,
                    PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);

```
            pageSettingsURL.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
            pageSettingsURL.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);

            pageSettingsURL.setParameter(
                "struts_action", "/layout_management/edit_pages");

            if (layout.isPrivateLayout()) {
                pageSettingsURL.setParameter("tabs1", "private-pages");
            }
            else {
                pageSettingsURL.setParameter("tabs1", "public-pages");
            }

            pageSettingsURL.setParameter("redirect", currentURL);
            pageSettingsURL.setParameter(
                "groupId", String.valueOf(scopeGroupId));
            pageSettingsURL.setParameter("selPlid", String.valueOf(plid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

themeDisplay.getURLPageSettings().toString()

You should get themeDisplay in jsp page if you are using

You should get themeDisplay as request attribute in your portlet class

Comment: It works, but it returns "Manage Page" url only for site (Layout) currently being displayed. What I need is to generate "URLPageSettings" for any given site (Layout) I have access to.